# Contractfilter mismatch at the endpointdispatcher wcf

Tags: iphone, wcf

I am requesting for a WCF method from my iphone application. But I always get a falutString in response.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:

                                 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                                 "<soapenv:Envelope \n"
                                 "xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \n"
                                 "xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\" \n"
                                 "xmlns=\"http://WssMobileService.Model/2012/ServiceContractDslModel\">\n"
                                 "<soapenv:Header/>\n"
                                 "<soapenv:Body>\n"
                                 "<tem:GetCompanies>\n"

                                 "<tem:ReqLogin>\n"

                                 "<UserName>%@</UserName>\n"

                                 "<Password>%@</Password> \n"

                                 "</tem:ReqLogin>\n"

                                 "</tem:GetCompanies>\n"

                                 "</soapenv:Body>\n"

                                 "</soapenv:Envelope>\n",username,password];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kMainURL];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];             
        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];          
        [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       
        [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/WssServiceContract/GetCompanies" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
        [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
        [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

**url** comes out to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns="http://WssMobileService.Model/2012/ServiceContractDslModel">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<tem:GetCompanies>
<tem:ReqLogin>
<UserName>something</UserName>
<Password>something</Password> 
</tem:ReqLogin>
</tem:GetCompanies>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the request I get for my request :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/WssServiceContract/GetCompanies' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I saw few StackOverflow solutions, but don't seem to be of any help.

Comment: Did you check the client and service to ensure contract and bindings are the same, as suggested in the error message?